# Форматирование строки с отступом каждые n символов

Tags: java, строки

Добрый день! Для лога требуется сделать вывод строк вида (одна цельная строка в n символов и каждая последующая с отступом в m символов, а так жепереносом спустя n символов):

```
2017.04.20 23:22:34: какое-то нужное сообщение, которое пере
                     носится вот таким вот образом, каждые n
                     символов
```

Как я понял, для этого используются то ли регулярные выражения, то ли форматирование, но так толком и не понял, как это правильно делается.

---

Вопрос: как правильно сделать форматирование строки требуемого для меня вида?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш вопрос понятен. Только вот зачем изобретать велосипеды? Ведь есть уже существующие логеры и можно пользоваться ими. Так будет проще и в некоторых ситуациях даже лучше. О том какие есть логеры и как ими пользоваться можете почитать [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247647/)

Ну а если уж прям хочется сделать вывод самому, то нужно разбить входную строку на несколько подстрок. Сделать это можно с помощью регулярных выражений. Ну а потом дописать вывод.

```
void log(String s, int n) {
  String[] lines = s.split(String.format("(?<=\\G.{%d})", n));
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  Date date = cal.getTime();             
  SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd KK:MM:SS");
  String timeStr = format1.format(date);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < timeStr.length(); i++)
    sb.append(" ");
  String spaceStr = sb.toString();
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0)
        System.out.print(timeStr);
    else
        System.out.println(spaceStr);
    System.out.print(lines[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Про логеры я знаю. Просто задача вывести все сообщения в сервлет. Я написал свой класс, который не требует конфигурации. Просто выводить лог в сервлет и, если нужно, файл. Получилось компактно и как раз, как мне нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от логгера, обычно формат вывода задается конфигурационными настройками логгера, например, для Log4J это задается т.н. `PatternLayout`, типа:

```
[%p] %d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %M - %m%n
```

[RTFM](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)